# Javascript / jQuery: How to check if date is last day of month

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, date, for-loop

I have the following code (shortened) which creates the dates of a month while looping through an array.

This works fine so far but I am struggling to **stop it if it reaches the last day of a month**. 
I am using this to dynamically add table rows to an HTML table and as the array is set to end at 31 it always starts with the next month when the set month has less than 31 days. The cells in my table then show e.g. ...`28, 29, 1, 2` for the February column.

Can someone tell me how I can check whether `day1`, `day2` or `day3` are the last day of the month and if set them to '' ?

My thought was that the following will give me the last day of a month but I couldn't find a way to work this in here and to use it properly for the comparisons:

```
var d = new Date(y, m+1, 0);
```

**My JS (shortened):**

```
$('#btnStart').on('click', function(){
    var date1, day1;
    var date2, day2;            

    var d = 0;
    var m = 0;  // user input
    var y = 2015; // user input
    for (d = 0; d <= 30; d++) {
        date1 = new Date(y, m, d+1);
        day1 = date1.getDate();
        date2 = new Date(y, m+1, d+1);
        day2 = date2.getDate();
    }
});
```

**Update:** This is only needed within a given year so it will never go from December to January.

Many thanks for any help with this, 
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use date.getTime() to compare dates.

Working jsbin with your example code:

http://jsbin.com/puhuvirize/2/edit?js,output

This will give you the last day of month 'm':

```
new Date(y, m + 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this as well ! - After playing with the different approaches this turned out to work best for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

If you add one day to the date, and the resulting date is the first of next month, then the examined date was the last day of its month.

something like

`isLast = (new Date(examinedDate.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000).getDate()) === 1`

Comment: simple, not bad at all

Comment: Thanks a lot - this works great and is even easier to implement in my case than other approaches.

Comment: This is genius - thanks... here's my code that works just great (selected_date being a new Date() already) `if(new Date(selected_date.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000).getDate() === 1) is_end_of_month = true;`

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your For loop

```
if(day2 < day1)
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't work as day2 will always be greater than day1 in this approach.

Answer (score 1):

with a simple function perhaps:

```
function isLastDay(y, m, d)
{
    var d1 = (m < 11) ? new Date(y, m + 1, 0) : new Date(y, 0, 0);
    var d2 = new Date(y, m, d);
    return (d1.getTime() === d2.getTime());
}
```

Comment: the 0 (zero) in new Date(y, m + 1, 0); gives you the last day of the previous month

Comment: This will always be false as the the date object d1 and the date object d2 are never the same.

Comment: @slash197: Thanks for this ! Can you explain the last line ?

Comment: @OleK: Thanks for your comment: I saw this as well and just updated the line in the post.

Comment: @keewee279 converts date objects to numbers so you can compare them accurately

Comment: @slash197: Thanks ! What does it return if d2 is greater than d1 and what if not ?

Comment: return true if date provided is the last day of month and false if it's not

Comment: @slash197: Thanks again ! Now I got it. Sorry I am pretty new to JS. This does the trick. :)